# How was Goku able to teleport to the "Other World"?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

In DBZ, Goku has teleported several times to the "Other World" *(a place presumably inhabited by souls)*, his most significant trip there being when he brought Cell in his second form there to prevent him from blowing up the earth and one another occasion Piccolo was summoned there too before being summoned to Namek. King Kai's planet is at the end of Snake Way and Snake Way is in the "Other World".

*This brings about the question of where exactly is it located and wouldn't that mean that a 'dead' Goku could have easily teleported back to earth just the same as if he were alive?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He could (And he sometimes did), but it's "forbidden", and Goku doesn't like breaking rules.

It's actually a different world in the same "dimension" as the normal world, so yes, Goku can freely teleport between the two.

Comment: Looking at this again, it correlates with the answer posted by Roy below and is actually more accurate in the sense that he can but it's forbidden. It's also worth noting that on these occasions he didn't do anything significant that would presumably alter the future.

Answer (score 7):

You're right in a technical sense.

From http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Instant_Transmission

> Goku can even shift through realms, having no problem teleporting from Earth to King Kai's planet, and from there to New Namek.

I think it's a matter of wanting to do it or not. Goku wants Gohan to grow up and reach his full potential, Goku believes his son can and will follow his steps as earth's protector. This can only happen if Gohan shakes away all his fears, and you can see how that happens as he destroys Cell.